# How to link to a php file that is in a folder named php

Tags: php

I have made my first website and I have a simple contact form that runs a php scripts to send the details inputted in the form to my email. I initially had all the files in the root directory but I am trying to tidy it up so I now have,

all html files in the root directory, I then have folders for php, css, assets, js.

I know that to link to these I need to just do something like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contactus.css"/>
```

I believe this tells the html to look in the root directory, then in css folder and for the file contactus.css.

This seems to work for all the css files but not for the php file ( I get a 404 error). I know this file is correct as when all the files where in the root folder it worked fine.

I currently have,

```
<form action="php/contactform.php" method="post">
```

I believe my issue is that when using href it will automatically start in the root folder but as I am not using href in this case it is not starting in the root folder. So I just need to find out what I use to link to a different folder to that of the html file (If I put the php file back in the root folder it works fine.

DIR structure

[image]

Comment: I think I know what the problem is but just need to confirm it. Can you post a screenshot or breakdown how the project DIR structure looks like so I can recommend solution

Comment: if what you believed is true, you might try changing it to `../php/contactform.php`

Comment: You should add your folder structure to the question. `I believe this tells the html to look in the root directory` - No. It checks from the current location you're at. If the HTML is at project root, then yes - it starts at root, however if you're inside another folder you would need to add `../` at start of the path to go back and into another one.

Comment: if your contactform is in the same dir with your php code that output <form action..", then remove php/ from action.  
note : css href="subdir/xxx.css"  search  in subdir of current file, and done, it don't looks in multiple location.  
for action="subdir/script.php" , is the same search, except if you work with auto_loader or with a framework like zend or symphonie, or cake,etc...)

Comment: @Shizukura never work with absolute path, It's a verry bad practice, when you move your script in a real server, it will never work, except if you code directly in your real server...

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the directory

Comment: Maybe start by _properly_ explaining what “not working” _actually_ means here. Do you get a 404 after submitting the form? Or an Internal Server Error? A “blank page”? Something else altogether?

Answer (score 1):

The action and href attributes work exactly same. The final url depends on how you've written the url in these parameters and what is your current url.

Let's say the current url is `http://localhost/my-project/html/my-form.html`

If your url in action looks like `php/contactform.php` this is called path relative url. To get final url the browser will append relative url after last `/` in current url resulting in `http://localhost/my-project/html/php/contactform.php`.

You can use `..` in the relative url if you want to reference directory higher in the structure. Url `../php/contactform.php` will result in `http://localhost/my-project/php/contactform.php`

If your url in action looks like this `/php/contactform.php` it is root relative url. The main difference is the starting `/`. In this case the browser will put your url right after the domain name resulting in `http://localhost/php/conactform.php`.

Based on your screenshot both `/php/contactform.php` and `php/contactform.php` should work fine because the url of the html file should be `http://your-domain.example/DJ_contactme.html` so both urls should result in `http://your-domain.example/php/contactform.php`

If you are using mod_userdir your url probably looks like `http://your-domain.example/~dannyjeb/DJ_contactme.html` in that case the `php/contactform.php` should work as it would result in `http://your-domain.example/~dannyjeb/php/contactform.php`

Answer (score 0):

From DJ_Contactme.html you target css file like this:

**`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/contactus.css"/>`**